# Interactions between oxytocin and prolactin after birth

Tags: oxytocin

## **Context**

I am currently working on a research about the relation between children's first years of life and the managment of emotional emptiness in maturity, e.g. smoking habits, eating disorders, onychophagia, bruxism, etc.

## **Information found**

I do know both oxytocin and prolactin are needed for lactation, as it says in [this article](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/565623_2):

> Prolactin stimulates milk biosynthesis within the alveolar cells of the breast and oxytocin stimulates contraction of the myoepithelial cells that surround the alveoli, causing the milk to be ejected into the ducts leading to the nipple.

Also, as Michel Odent points out in *Le bébé est un mammifère*, when a mother gives birth to a child, a peak of oxytocin is released stimulated by the very first moment of physical contact. I can deduce that if there is no contact, neither the oxytocin peak will occur.

## **Question**

Now, does somebody know if prolactine levels are affected by the peak of oxytocin caused by mother-child contact? e.g. Lower levels of oxytocin could lead to lower levels of prolactin and affect lactation.